# Where should I ask this SharePoint data upload question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

[My question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1676827/upload-directly-to-sharepoint-from-another-website) was closed. I assumed the question needed to be at Super User since there is no code involved.

Here's the question:

> #### Upload directly to SharePoint from another website
>
> Is it possible to use `Curl` or requests with either JavaScript or
> Python to transfer or copy data from one website to another?
>
> Goal - We use an email provider called Intermedia; they give you an
> option to download a PST of a customer's email as a backup. Instead of
> download the emails to our computer, we wanted to download it to a
> SharePoint repository we have.
>
> We know how to upload and download data from SharePoint using the
> Microsoft Graph API, but is it possible to upload data to SharePoint
> that is from another website; without having to download the data to a
> computer locally first?

Where should I ask this question?

Comment: Have you taken a look at ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I took a look and it seems none of the sites will take my question about website data transfers. Thanks again. I'll make sure to use that link when making a question.

Comment: It should be stated that the reason your question was closed was due to the fact it was overly broad.  It is possible to download and upload files using Curl, reading into your question (which is the last thing you want a reader to do), is if it's possible to perform a Curl upload operation into SharePoint. [It certainly seems possible](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205271/).  "Is it possible ...?" questions, rarely make good quality questions, that fit in our standard Q&A format.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [question about using cURL to upload files to SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/205271/61378) on [The SharePoint SE site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com). Try asking on that site.

Initially I checked the [which site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on/129632#129632) Meta post and saw there is a [sharepoint tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint) on [Web Applications SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).